# How to reduce the line spacing within the paragraph

Tags: line-spacing

I would like to reduce the line spacing for some sentences of a paragraph, for example, the blue color sentences as below, how should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] {\color{blue}\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The task isn't clear: what t do when the blue text starts inside a line?

The problem is that TeX uses `\baselineskip` value for whole paragraph when `\par` is processed.

Your example can be solved using two paragraphs, first one is black text and second one is blue text. First paragraph is finalized without stretchable `\parfillskip` and second paragraph is started with `\noindent` and with modified `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\endpar{{\parfillskip=0pt \par}
   \smallskip\baselineskip=10pt \lineskiplimit=-10pt \noindent}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] {\endpar\color{blue}\lipsum[2]\par}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't work if the part before the blue part is not long enough, in the sense that it may produce large interword spaces in the last line.

The idea is similar to [wipet's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685158/4427) but I use a proper LaTeX environment that avoids the need to do explicit `\par` and `\color` instructions, besides getting the top line spacing right without any need to guess.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for the example

\setstretch{1.2}

\newenvironment{innerpar}[1]{%
  {\unskip\strut\parfillskip=0pt \par}%
  \vspace*{0.2\baselineskip}%
  \setstretch{1}\noindent\ignorespaces\color{#1}%
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{innerpar}{blue!60}
\lipsum[2]
\end{innerpar}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]